# ZAPIER / send emails (newsletters) from gmail to pocket matching search query fails due to pocket requiring URL

Tags: zapier

Pocket requires a URL to read from however 1)the email does not necessarily have a URL or  2) the URL is within the HTML of the email.

If 2) I'd have to find and parse the desktop view of the email but this may not always be available.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If the email doesn't have a url, then there's no (simple) way to send it to pocket. A non-simple approach could be sending the content of the email to a different service (that'll generate a link) and then sending *that* link to pocket.

If there's a link in the email, you might try Zapier's `Extract URL` action in `Formatter by Zapier` ([docs](https://zapier.com/apps/formatter/help#extracting-and-structuring-text)), which can pull urls out of text. I'm not sure what sort of source you're working with (and how many urls the email has) but that will find something.

Comment: The sources are 2 types

1. Full email content is within the email such as a long email. This may or may not have online version. If so, I could extract the URL then send that to pocket